# How many flowers do I need for a 3 star rating?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Is there a specific target of flowers that I need to get a 3 star rated island? I have Nook's Cranny, Able Sisters, more than 25 outdoor furniture items and a full villager count etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at this article: https://kotaku.com/animal-crossing-speedrun-shows-k-k-slider-isnt-that-pi-1842796083

Namely this excerpt:

> It takes about 250 invisible “points” to reach three stars. Orcastraw outlines some of the criteria in a Pastebin:
>
> The basic logic is as follows:
>
> - Small non-crafted item: 2 Points(think flower in a vase, or a cardboard box, or a chair)
> - Valuable non-crafted item: 3 points(the switch! it’s worth 30k bells)
> - Basic crafted item: 3 Points(chairs, stools, birdbaths, anything that doesn’t require a lot of resources)
> - Efforted crafted item: 4-5 Points(The apple tv requires 10 apples and gives 4 points, and the crafting table gives FIVE, so think that kinda ballpark)
> - Public Works Project-escue items: 7 Points(The light pole gives this many points, and I imagine the other special nook miles-only items give that same amount, it’s a lot)
> - Fences affect points also, in a roundabout way, with DECIMALS.
>     50 fences = 20 points, so do the math there? Idk